# Why is the text not aligning to the top?

Tags: css, positioning

I have a text block in a div that is floated to the right. The div should align to the top but it has bumped down about 100px. See the text box next to the red flower here: http://174.121.46.122/~flowerwo/inside.html

I tried absolution positioning but when I do the background image disappears. It should be obvious where the text needs to be but it won't align properly.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="small-box">
<div id="small-box-top">
<div id="small-box-bot">
<div id="text-box">
<h3><a href="#">Headline</a></h3> 
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
</div>
<img class="small-box-photo" src="_images/flower-red.jpg" alt="flower" /> 
</div>
</div>
</div><!-- end small box -->
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#small-box  { 
    width: 625px; 
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px 0 0 5px;
    background: url(../_images/bg_small-box-mid.jpg) repeat-y; }
#small-box-top          { width: 625px; background: url(../_images/bg_small-box-top.jpg) no-repeat center top; }
#small-box-bot          { width: 625px; background: url(../_images/bg_small-box-bot.jpg) no-repeat left bottom; }

img.small-box-photo     { width: 245px; height: 258px; margin: 20px 0 20px 20px; position: relative; }
#text-box
```

Any help getting this to align properly to the top will be appreciated.

```
            { width: 300px; float: right; margin: 0 30px 0 0; }
```

Comment: You just posted a link pointing to your own hard-drive. It doesn't work like that.

Comment: Why would someone down vote this question?  I think if you down vote you should comment why so the poster knows for future reference.

Comment: Do you have the URL for the page so we can look at it fully?

Comment: Corrected link to the page. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#small-box-bot => display: table;

img.small-box-photo => float: left;
```

Comment: or display: inline-block, if you dont need to support old IEs

Comment: It works perfect. Why does the display:table make the difference?

Comment: friendly speaking, dont know. just know from experience.

Answer (score 1):

It does work as expected for me. Take a look at [this example](http://www.webdevout.net/test?08). Doesn't it look like what you try to achieve? If no, give more information and, preferably, the link to online version where we can see the issue.

UPDATE AFTER THE ONLINE EXAMPLE.

So, in the example you gave, there is the problem with clearing happening when:

1. the `#r-box-lower` clears the right floating with `clear: right`
2. the `#r-box-lower` sits at the same DOM level as `#small-box`, containing the weirdly shifted block of text
3. because of the p.1 and p.2 the `#text-box` is being cleared by `#r-box-lower` that makes it start right where `#r-box-lower` starts.

So, to fix the issue, you need to wrap `#right-box` and `r-box-lower` into a shared div like:

```
<div id="right-column" style="float: right; width: 192px">
    <div id="right-box">
        …
    </div>
    <div id="r-box-lower">
        …
    </div>
</div>
```

Surely, you want to move those inline styles into your stylesheet.

Comment: I see what you are saying here. It is the division of the boxes that is blocking the text.